# Не могу получить данные из свойства объекта. Работаю с google calendar api

Tags: javascript, объекты, fullcalendar

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var eTag = $('[e-tag]');
      console.log(eTag.prevObject[0].links);

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'interaction', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendar'],
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        evenLimit: true,
        displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view
        // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
        // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
        // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

        // US Holidays
        events:

        {
          googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCPvhWcgYRCc0foSHBGM0-RyyCMVX3AQ4Q',
          googleCalendarId: 'dmitriy.nikolaev1337@gmail.com'
        },
        eventClick: function (arg) {
          // opens events in a popup window
          window.open(arg.event.url, '_blank', 'width=1000,height=600');
          // prevents current tab from navigating
          arg.jsEvent.preventDefault();
          console.log(arg.event)
        },
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
    // var obj = {
    //   string: 'str',
    //   func: function () { }
    // };

    // var prop = 'func';

    // console.log(obj[prop])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

В свойстве links( красная черточка) находится мероприятия календаря, которые мне надо получить и работать с ними дальше, но если я обращаюсь к ним через точку выдает ошибку *undefined*